# Dangers of using the same GUID in interface definitions?

Tags: delphi, interface, guid

Suppose:

1) *HelpfulUserAtSO* answers my SO question with a snippet copied from his production code:

```
type
  IReqBase = Interface(IInterface)
  ['{B71BD1C3-CE4C-438A-8090-DA6AACF0B3C4}']
    procedure FillWithTemplateData;
  end;
```

2) I think *Great answer!* and blindly copy this into my production code.

3a) We both distribute our apps and user X wants to install both executables on his computer.
What are the consequences?

3b) I buy up HelpfulUserAtSO's company and want to integrate his code (containing the interface definition) into mine (containing the copy. Assume no scoping conflicts).
What are the consequences?

After all a GUID should be 'globally unique'...

Comment: The fault is where you copy the GUID. While there are a lot of cases where you must do exactly that, there are at least that much cases where you are supposed to create your own GUID. This isn't especially related to foreign code but is valid also for your own code in the same and in different applications.

Comment: Side note: the Delphi compiler (or the IDE) should issue a warning when a GUID is not unique in the project, for example as the result of a copy and paste operation - see [Is there a tool which detects duplicate interface GUIDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793095/is-there-a-tool-which-detects-duplicate-interface-guids)

Comment: @mjn Sometimes, you may define the same GUID in the same project, e.g. if the same COM object is addressed several times. It should check for the interface signature of all methods before issuing a warning... not so easy... but indeed possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the same GUID are used not within the same process, this is safe to have the same GUID defined. But if, e.g. you access them via COM, it will definitively be confusing.

If you use diverse interfaces with the same GUID in the same process, e.g. by sharing Delphi code units, you may definitively have issues. By convention, an unique GUID should define an unique signature (i.e. set of methods), so the code may think that a given class instance implements all methods of the interface, and it won't be the case. As a result, the internal execution lookup tables (IMT) won't match. You will get a lot of A/V when calling methods.

[image: IMT interface table]

Take a look [at this very complete article](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/delphi-interfaces-on-binary-level/) for details about how interfaces work, and what is this internal IMT lookup table. The same GUID would mean the same IMT table, which won't be the case for you, so it will just break at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced an error due to using duplicated GUID for a new interface that's copied from another.

The consequence was that, since I use `Supports`, although I was intended to call `InterfaceB.Method`, but `InterfaceA.Method1` got called wrongly even it has a different method signature...I found that with the IDE debugger.

The compiler really should report duplicated interface GUIDs as an error.